# TypeError: cleanUrl is not a function while creating a React Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, cmd

Hey everybody I am getting this error after hosting a website on firebase or I am not sure about it.

[image]

[image]

It's the replace-info.js screenshot.

I am not able to  find the solution on stackoverflow or on other website.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Add actual code in the Question body instead of images and screenshots

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

This error had appeared on my side after *npm update npm@lastest*

What I did to fix it:

1. Go to *AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\lib\index.js*.
2. Add `module.exports.cleanUrl = require('./clean-url.js')` at the end of the file.

P.S. I just copied it from there https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-fetch/blob/main/lib/index.js